# How to upgrade a tbz package that I create in Freebsd?

Tags: freebsd, package-management, upgrade

I want to learn way of upgrade a package. I created a package on my development server and I installed it to test server by

```
pkg_add foo-1.0.tbz
```

then I changed version of package as 1.1.

In my freebsd test server there is only  `pkg-config, pkg_add, pkg_create, pkg_delete, pkg_info, pkg_updating, pkg_version` commands. I figure out none of these commands used for upgrade a package.

Now, I can only install a new package after delete older version.

```
pkg_delete foo-1.0
pkg_add foo-1.1.tbz
```

Is this the only way? or is there any gracefully way to upgrade a package?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the way one upgrades packages via pkg_add. The question has been touched here before: https://serverfault.com/questions/214611/handling-freebsd-package-upgrades-using-pkg-add .